# how to set quantity in darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart package?

Tags: laravel

I want to set a quantity for my items in darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart but it doesn't set and when I get dd there is no quantity in item. It's my cart controller:

```
public function add(Request $request)
    {

        $product = Product::findOrFail($request->product_id);
        $rowId = $product->id;
                Cart::add(array(
                'id' => $rowId,
                'name' => $product->name,
                'price' => $product->is_sale ? $product->sale_price : $product->price,
                'quantity' => 1,
                'attributes' => $product->toArray(),
                'associatedModel' => $product
            ));
        
            return redirect()->back();
    }
```

I'm using laravel 8 and I updated the package to latest version

Comment: I assume you're using this package: https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart, which does say: *"Laravel 5 & 6 & 7 Shopping Cart"* - Make sure it works for Laravel 8 (nevermind; it supports up to 9, the `readme.md` file is wrong). But, the docs do show `'quantity' => 4` as a valid example: https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart#quick-usage-example. Might be better to check the open issues or post a new one there: https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart/issues

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you add this ?

   `<input type="number" name="quantity">`
2. if So, you can get the quantity in add function by this

   `'quantity' => $request->quantity`